# Css-selector is not able to identify element in WEBVIEW in iOS hybrid app(build in Ionic+angular) while doing e2e testing using Appium

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, automated-tests, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am doing e2e testing on iPhone 11 (real device) for a hybrid app built using ionic +angular and using CSS-selector to click/tap elements. It can not identify the text field even though it is available in the webview. I also tried to access the text field via XPATH but it did not work either.

Angular: 10.1.5
Angular CLI: 10.1.6
Node: 14.15.4
typescript: 4.0.3
ionic : 5.2.3
appium : 1.20.2

I also read this thread: https://discuss.appium.io/t/not-able-to-identify-element-in-webview-in-ios-hyprid-app-build-in-ionic-automation-using-appium-on-real-device/10244/8

Until now, it was not able to identify.
Please let me know if anyone of you has any leads regarding this issue.

Thanks

Sukriti

Comment: Hey! Try to check context (driver.getContextHandles()), probably it's need to switch in web-view.  Also try to use iOS Predicate String Strategy [https://appiumpro.com/editions/8-how-to-find-elements-in-ios-not-by-xpath], check your locator in desktop appium

Comment: Hi @dmytroMinz, thanks for the suggestions! I will try these.